# Ejabberd/XMPP Chat Server

Tags: node.js, xmpp, ejabberd

I am looking to build a chat server using EJABBERD and XMPP but don't know how to start. Can anyone share with me good docs/tutorials to follow as a beginner.

Also, does ejabberd include a database for storing chat messages, if so please provide some help as to where to begin.

I have tried using Nodejs and socket.io but I faced multiple problems such as ghost connections, duplicate messages on android client. So, I have decided to look at some alternatives.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the most complete XMPP library for Node.js is [node-xmpp](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/tree/node-xmpp), but it lacks documentation

Answer (score 0):

Your start point is

1) For xmpp server : https://github.com/processone/ejabberd or https://prosody.im

2) Read Book: xmpp definitive guide

3) Read blog for android client: http://www.blikoontech.com/tutorials/android-smack-xmpp-introductionbuilding-a-simple-client

Yes, ejabberd provides MySQL support to store chat messages.